# Bugzilla config fails: ./data/params.json file does not exist

Tags: bugzilla

I already installed successfully LAMP on suse tumbleweed.
Then i installed bugzilla with yast.
When directing browser to `localhost/bugzilla` i get

```
Software error:

The ./data/params.json file does not exist. You probably need to run checksetup.pl. at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 341.
Compilation failed in require at /srv/www/bugzilla/index.cgi line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /srv/www/bugzilla/index.cgi line 15.
```

Ok, there seems to be a solution to that.
Enter `/srv/www/bugzilla` and then

```
./checksetup.pl
```

But still this does not work as feedbck is:

```
...
***********************************************************************
* APACHE MODULES                                                      *
***********************************************************************
* Some Apache modules allow to extend Bugzilla functionalities.       *
* These modules can be enabled in the Apache configuration file       *
* (usually called httpd.conf or apache2.conf).                        *
* - mod_headers, mod_env and mod_expires permit to automatically      *
*   refresh the browser cache of your users when upgrading Bugzilla.  *
* - mod_rewrite permits to write shorter URLs used by the REST API.   *
* - mod_version permits to write rules in .htaccess specific to       *
*   Apache 2.2 or 2.4.                                                *
* The modules you need to enable are:                                 *
*                                                                     *
*    mod_headers, mod_rewrite                                         *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
```

W Craig told me that these are not perl modules but apache modules
and so i enabled them via

```
a2enmod mod_headers
a2enmod mod_rewrite
```

Then i ran

```
localhost:/srv/www/bugzilla # ./checksetup.pl
```

again but the result is strange:

```
* This is Bugzilla 5.0.6 on perl 5.30.1
* Running on Linux 5.8.4-1-default #1 SMP Wed Aug 26 10:53:09 UTC 2020 (64fe492)
...
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     not found 
...
Checking for           File-Which (any)       ok: found v1.23 
Checking for              mod_env (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_expires (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_headers (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_rewrite (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_version (any)       ok 
Undefined subroutine utf8::SWASHNEW called at Bugzilla/Util.pm line 109.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 21, <DATA> line 755.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 21, <DATA> line 755.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 22, <DATA> line 755.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 22, <DATA> line 755.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla.pm line 23, <DATA> line 755.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla.pm line 23, <DATA> line 755.
Compilation failed in require at ./checksetup.pl line 76, <DATA> line 755.
loc
```

What is interesting, mod_rewrite has no version.
A module is missing and sth is wrong at auth/mailer.

By the way, the message of my browser is unchanged.
Still `./data/params.json` is missing
and it looks like a missing perl ..... thing. ;-)

Ok, next i found a site, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1588175, describing the first of my errors.
They advise to comment out /srv/www/bugzilla/Bugzilla/Util.pm:
$var =~ tr/\x{202a}-\x{202e}//d;
This improves the situation.

Ok, still

```
There was an error connecting to MySQL:
    Access denied for user 'bugs'@'localhost'
```

This brings me to the point, that i never defined such a user.
Thus i logged in `mysql -u root` and defined a user:

```
CREATE USER 'bugs'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'bugs';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bugs'@localhost;
```

Then I tried again... This time:

```
There was an error connecting to MySQL:
    Access denied for user 'bugs'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Ah, clear, i have to specify the password.
So i did `vi localconfig` and corrected `$db_pass = 'bugs';`.
Then again `./checksetup.pl`.
This time a lot of output.
But still last line is no good:

```
There is no such group: apache. Check your $webservergroup setting in
./localconfig.
```

Now `ps aux | grep apache` unveils that apache has login name `wwwrun`
and i found that it is in groups `wwwrun` and `www`.
I tried to enter the first in `./localconfig`, i.e. replaced
`$webservergroup = 'apache';` by `$webservergroup = 'wwwrun';`
(of course, commenting out, not just changing.)

Ok, again i tried `./checksetup.pl` and this time i am asked for many things
as email address and password for mail..
and at the end `checksetup.pl complete`.

Reload of http://localhost/bugzilla/ in browser
shows sth different this time:

```
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. 
There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
```

Ah, I have

```
drwxr-x--- 1 root wwwrun 2076 Sep 10 21:07 bugzilla
```

So this seems ok and i have an index.cgi inside:

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 root wwwrun 2171 Aug 25 19:42 index.cgi
```

Now I had the idea of checking `/var/log/apache2/error_log`
and the last lines are

```
[Thu Sep 10 21:11:07.869216 2020] [core:crit] [pid 17926] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:34306] AH00529: /srv/www/bugzilla/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/srv/www/bugzilla/' is executable
```

Ah! it is the .htaccess.
I found out that `./checksetup.pl` creates all .htaccess in subdirs
but not in the base.
In the base, that file is just MISSING!!!!
Even if i copy from subdirs, i dont get bugzilla run...

What can i do????

Answer (score 0):

Those modules listed are Apache modules, not perl modules.

Use a2enmod to enable them.

Comment: I tried this also.. but ... no success still. 
I updated my question.

Comment: If you’ve enabled those modules, the check script should not list them as needing to be enabled.  Did you restart Apache?

Comment: yes is restarted apache.. well, the script is fine with the modules now.. I think i am one step further... 
I update the question, wait please.