# Bugzilla installation fails: .htaccess missing

Tags: apache2, opensuse, bugzilla

I already installed successfully LAMP on suse tumbleweed. Then i installed bugzilla with yast.
This makes the impression that installation is out of the box.
But then... see

```
https://serverfault.com/questions/1033282/bugzilla-config-fails-data-params-json-file-does-not-exist
```

with the story what happened.
After some steps I arrived at the problem that
directing browser to localhost/bugzilla yields

```
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. 
There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
```

This is misleading because according to the error log `/var/log/apache2/error_log` the problem is

```
[Thu Sep 10 21:11:07.869216 2020] [core:crit] [pid 17926] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:34306] AH00529: /srv/www/bugzilla/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/srv/www/bugzilla/' is executable
```

Having a close look it turns out that `.htaccess` is missing completely.
What is strange is, that this is so although i ran `./checksetup.pl`
and the `.htaccess` files in the subdirectories are created,
but no the one in the root.

What went wrong and what shall I do now???

Comment: You have already written all of this in the previous post. What is different here?

Comment: I shortcut the path because no one answers to the current question. On one hand, i want to direct you to the current question (what to do with missing .htaccess) on the other hand, i think i shall give you a chance to see (in the link) how i came to the current config. Maybe there is the problem. Sorry.